# undefined reference to object method in it's property on jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces, closures

I have problem in line #27 (fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hh82p4fj/1/)

Why my property points to `undefined` while it's in the same closure?

```
"use strict";

function callself(instance, callback) { // saves 'this' state for reuse inside another function
    return function () {
        var argumentsList = [this], i;

        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i = i + 1) {
            argumentsList.push(arguments[i]);
        }

        return callback.apply(instance, argumentsList);
    };
}

var Namespace = function () {
    var settings = { handler: this.method };

    this.initialize = function () {
        $.fn.myPlugin = callself(this, function (that, userInput) {
            /* this = Namespace
               that = jQuery element
               userInput = provided in line 30 as parameter
            */
            console.log(this);
            console.log(that);
            console.log(userInput);
            console.log(settings.handler); // why why it's undefined?
        });

        $('body').myPlugin('someData');
    };

    this.method = function () { console.info('method'); }; // this method should be returned as reference in line 27, but it can not reah 'this` - don't know why
};
new Namespace().initialize();
```

`callself` is needed there, to preserve both jQuery `this` context ando ryginal object closure.

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hh82p4fj/2/

Comment: place `this.method = function () {...` before `var settings=` beacuse **this.method** is **undefined** when you defining `settings`

Comment: @Tushar your fiddle still returns `undefined` there :-)

Comment: @Ultra fiddle is not mine :D mine comment is correct. tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var settings = { handler: this.method };
```

You **assigned** to `settings.handler` **not a reference** to `this.method`
**but value** of `this.method` (which is undefined at execution moment)

`this.method` must be an **object** to get referenced.

---

```
this.method = {}; //empty object
var settings = { handler: this.method };
```

> `this.method` =><sub>ref</sub> **{}**
>   
>  `settings.handler` =><sub>ref</sub> **{}**

---

```
this.method = {}; //empty object
var settings = { handler: this.method };
this.method = funtion(){}`// reference will be replaced
```

> `this.method` =><sub>ref</sub> **funtion(){}**
>   
>  `settings.handler` =><sub>ref</sub> **{}**

---

```
this.method = {}; //empty object
var settings = { handler: this.method };
this.method.use = function(){}
```

> `this.method` =><sub>ref</sub> **{use: function(){}}**
>   
>  `settings.handler` =><sub>ref</sub> **{use: function(){}}**

---

```js
function Namespace(){
  
    var settings = {};

    this.initialize = function(){
        document.write(settings.handler())
    };

    settings.handler = function(){return 'Handled!'};
}
new Namespace().initialize()
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the order of initialization.

You are using `this.method` at the be genning of the script when `this.method = function(){}` is not yet executed so the value of `this.method` is undefined when the setting object is created.

```
var Namespace = function () {
    //this should be set before `this.method` is referred
    this.method = function () {
        console.info('method');
    };

    var settings = {
        handler: this.method
    };

    this.initialize = function () {
        $.fn.myPlugin = callself(this, function (that, userInput) {
            /* this = Namespace
               that = jQuery element
               userInput = provided in line 30 as parameter
            */
            console.log(this);
            console.log(that);
            console.log(userInput);
            console.log(settings.handler); // why why it's undefined?
        });

        $('body').myPlugin('someData');
    };

};
```

Comment: I thought am passing a reference filled when `this.initialize` is executed (where it's existing).